# Is it safe to call a member function on a temporary object returned by a function (after the function return)?

Tags: c++

I have no idea if is it safe to call a temporary object's member function when the temporary object is created by (another) function and then returned.

The following is an example:

```
string getString(const string &str)
{
    string tempStr = str + str;

    return tempStr;
}

int main()
{
    if(getString("aaaaa").compare("bbbb") == 0) { // is it safe?
        // do something
    }
}
```

I also make a lifetime test as following.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " :" << this << endl;
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " :" << this << endl;
    }

    void show()
    {
        cout << this << endl;
    }
};

Foo func(void)
{
    return Foo();
}

int main()
{
   func().show();
   return 0;
}
```

result:

Foo::Foo()       :0x7fff4d03d3bf
**void Foo::show() :0x7fff4d03d3bf**
Foo::~Foo()      :0x7fff4d03d3bf

Seems the destructor will be launched after the member function finish.
But is it depending on the compiler?

PS: The compiler which I used is g++ v 5.3.1
Thanks

Answer (score 11):

A temporary object created by the return statement of a function that returns an object by value lives at least until the entire statement that invoked the function completes. So this is safe.

You aren't seeing `tempStr` destroyed because of the return value optimization. But the code would still be 100% safe even if `tempStr` was destroyed because the temporary you're accessing *isn't* `tempStr` but the one created by the return by value.